# Odoo - Emails not being sent from non admin user

Tags: email, server, odoo

When I click the "Send by Email" button on a quotation as any user other than the admin, email does not get sent. What can be the problem? I am using smtp.gmail.com as my outgoing mail server.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?? Did you get any error in the log?? Do you have an "Alias domain in the "General settings"? Do you have the correct "Messagin alias" in the "Preferences" tab of the user? Is this happening only with the quotations?

Comment: I am still unable to solve the issue. I am not getting any error in the log. Yes, I have an alias domain. Yes, I have the correct messaging alias. This is happening across the application, not just with the quotations.